# EntityFrameworkCore Context. SaveChanges no actualiza DDBB

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Lo primero agradecer la ayuda que pueda recibir. El problema lo estoy teniendo al guardar los cambios del contexto de la DDBB en una Aplicación de Servidor **ASP.Net 6** con **EntityFrameworkCore** 6 y SQL Server no verse modificada la misma. La conexión de DDBB se realiza correctamente, ya que las migraciones se efectúan a la perfección que realizan cambios en las tablas y relaciones de DDBB. Sin embargo, al registrar entidades hacia la Base de Datos, mediante el DBContext, no se aplican los cambios.

Se han realizado multitud de cambios buscando solución y no hay forma.
Os pongo en situación. Espero que alguien pueda solventar este problema. Gracias

*******************   Contexto     **************************

Aplicación de **Servidor Web Rest API** con:

- ASP.Net 6
- **Entity Framework Core 6**
- **SQL Server**

Se genera Proyecto "**Shared**" para integración de **Módulos** (o Modelos) compartidos entre aplicación Servidor y aplicación Cliente.

Dentro de cada Módulo se añaden:

- **Entidad**.
- **DTO**
- **Context**
- **Services**
- **Validators**
- **Datas** (constantes...)

- Los **Controladores** se agregarán dentro de la Aplicación de Servidor API.

Para la **Aplicación Cliente** se empleará:

- **Blazor Framework WebAssembly** Server Project.

Se definen las **Migraciones**, generando éstas mismas toda la Base de Datos (Tablas, campos, relaciones...). Por lo que existe conexión de DDBB. Se aplican los Create Table y Alter Table propios de la migración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se realizan múltiples cambios al código para buscar solución. *Se añaden algunos de esos cambios mediante **comentarios***. Se **encapsula** la **petición de Inseción** a la DDBB en un **Try/Catch** para capturar el Excepción. En ocasiones, ni siquiera genera Excepción (aunque sigua sin guardar datos en Base de Datos).

Fragmentos de Código:

```
    /***************** Program.cs  */
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DDBBGlobalContext>();
/* more... */

/***************** DDBBGlobalContext.cs */
public class DDBBGlobalContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Application"));
            optionsBuilder.UseExceptionProcessor();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        /* more... */
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UsuarioContext).Assembly);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    /* more... */
    public DbSet<UsuarioEntity> Usuario { get; set; }
}


/***************** UsuarioContext.cs */
public class UsuarioContext : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UsuarioEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UsuarioEntity> builder)
    {
    builder.ToTable("usuario")
            .HasKey(model => model.Id);
    builder.Property(model => model.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.HasMany(model => model.Instalaciones)
            .WithMany(model => model.Usuarios);
    }
}


/***************** UsuarioService.cs  */
public partial class UsuarioService
{
    private static DDBBGlobalContext _dbContext { get; set; } = null;
    public static UsuarioDto? ModelDto { get; set; } = null;
    private static UsuarioEntity? ModelEntity { get; set; } = null;

    public static async Task<UsuarioDto?> CreateOne(/* data */)
    {
        UsuarioDto? response;
        try
        {
            new UsuarioDto(/* data */);
            response = UsuariosList.Where(model => model.Email == _email).Single();
        }
        catch (Exception) // Capturamos Excepción para identificar Error.
        {
            response = null;
        }

        if (response != null)
        {
            bool Check = await CreateDDBBOne(/* data */);
        }

        return response;
    }

    public static async Task<bool> CreateDDBBOne(/* data */)
    {
        bool response;
        try
        {
        ModelEntity = new(){/* data */};

        _dbContext = new DDBBGlobalContext();
        _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        dynamic error; // Only in Debug Mode

        try
        {
            // var temp = _dbContext.Usuario.Add(ModelEntity);
            // var temp = _dbContext.Add<UsuarioEntity>(ModelEntity);
            var temp = _dbContext.Add(ModelEntity);

            // _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT usuario ON;");
            // var result = _dbContext.SaveChanges();




            // ################  ERROR AQUI   ###################

            var result = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


            // ################  FIN ERROR  ###################



            // _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT usuario OFF;");
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException exception) when (exception?.InnerException?.Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row in object") ?? false)
        {
            error = exception;
            if (error != null)
            {
                return error; //return the error string
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch (UniqueConstraintException ex)
        {
            error = ex;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error = e;  // e: InnerException = {"No se puede insertar un valor explícito en la columna de identidad de la tabla 'usuario' cuando IDENTITY_INSERT es OFF."}
                        // e: InnerException = {"No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'private_key', tabla 'usuario'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT.\r\nSe terminó la instrucción."}
        }

        response = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        var error = e;
    }
        return response;
    }
}


/********************** UsuarioEntity.cs */
[Table("usuario")]
public partial class UsuarioEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    /* more... */
}


/**********************  UsuarioDto.cs */
public partial class UsuarioDto
{
    private static int LastId { get; set; } = 0;

    public int Id { get; set; } = default(int);
    
    /* more... */

    public UsuarioDto(/* data */)
    {
        if (UsuariosList.Count() == 0 || CheckEmail(_email))
        {
                LastId++;
                Id = LastId;
            /* more... */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pregunta: Por qué la entidad `Usuario` tiene la propiedad `Id` como `nullable`? Por qué en la configuración de la entidad lo tienes como `.IsRequired()` Según la base de datos, `dbo.usuario.id` es una llave primaria, y `not null`. Qué es `LastId`? Tu problema no es claro. Qué es *DDBB*? *DataDataBaseBase*? Quieres insertar en la columna `Id`? No se puede sin `Identity_Insert ON` como en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896047/how-to-turn-on-identity-insert-in-net-core). Te estás complicando por gusto

Comment: Muchas gracias, Arriel,  por la respuesta. Lo primero... DDBB sí es Base de Datos. Terminología inglesa. Lo del Id de usuario... pues tienes razón. Pero eso no estaba así originariamente. Como he realizado 300 pruebas y he agotado las sugerencias de Google... en algún momento se me quedó en nullable y no lo restablecí a su valor original. El problema es que cuando realizo el método de EntityFramework para añadir un registro a la Base de Datos, por algún motivo no se aplican los cambios. A veces produce Excepcción que no se puede ingresar valor explícito en columna identidad.

Comment: Por cierto... con el Id no nullable, sigue fallando.

Comment: Por qúe hay dos configuraciones de `Usuario`? Estás usando `FluentAPI` en `UsuarioContext `, pero estás usando `DataAnnotations` en `UsuarioEntity`. También le estás diciendo `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` cuando debería ser `.Identity`. Por qué la doble configuración? Por cierto, "sigue fallando" no es descriptivo. Cuál es el error, el mensaje, la excepción?.